# If these problems are equivalent how can I prove that mathematically?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

If $\alpha\,\, and\,\, p$ are non-negative scalars, are the two problems given below equivalent? I know that the values of objective functions will be different but I want to know will they result in same values of $\alpha\,\, and\,\, p$. 
If they are equivalent, how can I prove it mathematically without drawing graphs or any thing like that. I am **not** a mathematician so I want to know is it possible to have a 7,8 line prof that would satisfy a mathematician that they are equivalent? Also will they be equivalent for $\alpha\geq1$ and in general will they be equivalent for any set of constraints as long as both problems have the same constraints?

\begin{align}
Problem 1:
\min_{\alpha_{1},p_{1},\alpha_{2},p_{2}}\alpha_{1}p_{1}+\alpha_{2}p_{2},\\ 
\text{subject to}: \alpha_{1}log(1+p_{1} )\geq5,\\ \alpha_{2}log(1+p_{2})\geq5,\\ \alpha_{1}\,\, and\,\, \alpha_{2}\leq1.\\
Problem 2:
\min_{\alpha_{1},p_{1},\alpha_{2},p_{2}}(\alpha_{1}p_{1})^{2}+(\alpha_{2}p_{2})^{2},\\ 
\text{subject to}: \alpha_{1}log(1+p_{1} )\geq5,\\ \alpha_{2}log(1+p_{2})\geq5,\\\alpha_{1}\,\, and\,\, \alpha_{2}\leq1 .\\
\end{align}

Comment: A notational detail: a mathematician would have posed the problem as "$(\alpha_{1},p_{1},\alpha_{2},p_{2})=Argmin(\alpha_{1}p_{1}+\alpha_{2}p_{2})$ (the values of ARGuments that generate a MIN). The same for the other function.

Comment: Actually, I (a mathematician) only just recently learned that notation from a data scientist.

Comment: @Lee Mosher You are right, it is rather recent and does not come from the "pure mathematics" community.

Comment: I just made a rather extensive simulation evidencing that these "argmin" are the same, i.e., the minima occur for the same values of $(\alpha_{1},p_{1},\alpha_{2},p_{2})$ which are $(1,1,e^5-1,e^5-1)$. It remains to prove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both problems are separable into two independent problems in $(\alpha_1,p_1)$ and $(\alpha_2,p_2)$, namely
$$
\min_{\alpha,p} \alpha p \quad \text{or} \quad \min_{\alpha,p}\,(\alpha p)^2 \\
\text{subject to } \alpha\log(1+p)\ge 5, \alpha \le 1.
$$
Since $\alpha p$ is nonnegative, squaring it makes no difference to the location of the minimum.

Comment: Thank you, all I need is a reference to this statement of yours, " squaring it makes no difference to the location of the minimum". Is this some kind of general rule or something? I really need a reference from a book or paper, I would really appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: I don't think you need a reference, you can just point out that $f(x)=x^2$ is monotonically increasing for $x\ge 0$. Equivalently, for nonnegative $x,y$, we have $x^2\le y^2$ if and only if $x\le y$. To spell out the proof of the statement: The minimum of $g(\alpha,p)$ occurs at $(\alpha^*,p^*)$ $\iff$ $g(\alpha^*,p^*)\le g(\alpha,p)$ for all $\alpha, p$ $\iff$ $g(\alpha^*,p^*)^2\le g(\alpha,p)^2$ for all $\alpha, p$ $\iff$ the minimum of $g(\alpha,p)^2$ occurs at $(\alpha^*,p^*)$.